# Bitlocker encrypted my drive without asking during Windows update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bitlocker

After my Windows 10 machine installed the latest seasonal update, it got stuck in a boot loop. It POSTs, but only got as far as the Dell loading screen - no Windows loading screen.

I swapped the OS drive into a another machine and found that the main partition had been encrypted with bitlocker. I did not set up bitlocker, nor was I prompted to set a password at any point, so now I have a drive that I cannot access unless I have a password which I was never asked to create. Any clue what happened and how I can recover?

Comment: BitLocker isn’t enabled automatically ever.  Turning on BitLocker, goes through a process, including giving the user the chance to backup a recovery key.  However, Device Encryption often by default enabled, I am guessing that’s the case here.  If your HDD is encrypted then, unless you turn off the encryption, data recovery will NOT be possible.  In the case of Device Encryption, the recovery key, is stored on your Microsoft Account.

Comment: I've booted this machine many times and never saw a bitlocker prompt. The machine does have a TPM, so if bitlocker was enabled, then it was using the TPM and not a password. Is it possible the Windows update caused a problem with my TPM?